# Is my data safe during system installation?

Tags: upgrade, system-installation, 64-bit, 32-bit

I want to move from 32-bit Ubuntu 14.04 to 64-bit Ubuntu 14.10 (or 14.04).

I've already read [Is it possible to "upgrade" from a 32bit to a 64bit installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5018/is-it-possible-to-upgrade-from-a-32bit-to-a-64bit-installation)

I ***DO NOT*** care about the previously installed packages, settings, preferences or anything else from 14.04.

I've already made a list of manually installed packages by following [drgrog](https://askubuntu.com/users/16741/drgrog)'s answer from [Find out what packages were installed after os install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464701/find-out-what-packages-were-installed-after-os-install) , which I will later use to make fresh install of relevant packages on 64-bit OS.

I am concerned about only ***non-OS*** data (docs, videos, downloaded files etc.)

Is backup still necessary? How to do it?

Comment: backup is always necessary! Also you will loose your data when you do the fresh install of the 64-bit system!

Comment: I would just copy the data I want to save to an external hard drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **only** measure to prevent data loss is:

## Backup

It is very easy to install/upgrade Ubuntu keeping your data safe and untouched but from [what we hear here](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=installation%20lost%20data) it is apparently also easy to accidentally do something wrong which for so many unfortunate people led to a data loss.

Therefore whenever I plan to upgrade or install an OS I always do my regular backup **before** I start. I almost never needed to restore anything from that however.