# list only third party packages in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: command-line, 18.04, dpkg

I am Creating a project to view and upgrade packages in Ubuntu. Is there any command for list only Third party software?

`dpkg --list` shows all packages installed in OS.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! What do you mean by third-party software? I can image multiple options: Software from 1. universe/multiverse repository, 2. non-Ubuntu repositories (PPAs, etc.), 3. manually installed using .deb files, 4. manually installed by other means…

Comment: hi [Melebus](https://askubuntu.com/users/250300/melebius) , sorry for the incomplete question. like in Windows OS,installed software can be categorize  as Microsoft or Non Microsoft software. like wise in linux , how can we categorize.

Comment: additianally is there any way only to list packages "manually installed by other means" or "manually installed using .deb files", or "non-Ubuntu repositories"?

Comment: _“in Windows OS,installed software can be categorize as Microsoft or Non Microsoft software.”_ This is not how the Linux world works. Linux software is generally made by _community_ and distributed by a [distro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution) maintainer which for Ubuntu is Canonical Inc. However, they haven’t developed all the provided software. What is the purpose of such a categorization?

Comment: when a fresh linux OS is installed, some packages may be already installed (by default). and later we install others by our requirement. can we list only packages we installs later

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find out what packages were installed after os install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464701/find-out-what-packages-were-installed-after-os-install) or [Generating list of manually installed packages and querying individual packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2389/generating-list-of-manually-installed-packages-and-querying-individual-packages).

Comment: The packages installed by the Ubuntu Desktop installer have two easily identifiable characterisics: The top-level package in the dependency chain is the *ubuntu-desktop* metapackage, and the packages are apt-marked as *manual* even though they were automatically installed.

Comment: @Melebius I think what the asker means by "third-party" (*a party other than the principals*) in this question is software that was not installed from the default Ubuntu repositories. I think the asker considers Ubuntu itself as the first party, the default Ubuntu repositories as the second party, and other software sources as third parties. The Ubuntu software sources are the principals and other software sources are third-party sources.

Comment: @karel I am afraid the definition you proposed is not valid. AFAIK these parties refer to a legal agreement – a license agreement if the software is concerned. It is made between a software supplier (the first party) and the user (the second party). The [third party](https://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-a-third-party-agreement.htm) is then anyone who extends/modifies the original agreement, i.e. provides some other software to the user. Anyway, you should include _your_ definition in your answer as it might miss OP’s expectations.

Comment: @Melebius It's going to Meta.

Comment: @karel Good choice! Please ping me and post a link here when the post is ready.

Comment: Clearly there's no point in going to Meta until the OP decides to make his opinion known about what he personally meant by "third-party". If the Ubuntu Software app gets ruled by the OP as a third-party app, I have no wish to dispute his definition because after all this is the OP's question, not mine. The words mean whatever the OP says they mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To list the packages installed from third-party repositories:

```
ubuntu-security-status --thirdparty
```

To list the locally installed or obsolete packages missing from any enabled repository:

```
ubuntu-security-status --unavailable
```

To further check the specifics, type in:

```
apt-cache policy <package_name>
```

Comment: I'm on 18.04, but ubuntu-security-status does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Using `apt` and grep to get local(-obsolete) packages, i.e. there is nothing in the package that identifies the origin of the package.

```
apt list --installed | \
    grep -F "$(gettext 'apt' '[installed,local]')"
```

Comment: 1. How does this refer to the “third party software”? 2. This won’t work in a localized version of Ubuntu unless `LC_ALL=C`, for example, is used.