# Cloned SSD not found

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, ssd

I know, there are a lot of posts regarding similar problems, but I tried and constantly failed.

I have a toshiba satellite z30b, with an SSD of 256Gb. I would like to substitute the SSD since it's full. The new SSD is a kingston mSata with 512Gb of memory.

I have both windows 10 and ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

I connected the new SSD with USB to the pc, and run clonezilla from liveUSB.
Everything goes fine, all the data and partition were copied, I can see them, but when I change the SSD and power on the pc it tells me "No disk found, please insert a disk and press a key."

I thought it was a grub problem, so I tried with SuperGrub2 but it wasn't able to see any OS on the new SSD.

If it can be helpful, here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3UOT.png) from Gparted of my **old** SSD partition and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpW8I.png) is the **new** SSD

Here's the boot-repair report: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/PxqXz9nyqY/

Could be something related to EFI or the multiple partitions?
Any suggestion?

Thanks in advice

**Last Update**
I had installed ubuntu in the new SSD, it starts when the SSD is connected from USB but it doesn't start when it is connect directly on the motherboard. This means BIOS cannot read the SSD, it doesn't have the right drivers. Unfortunately, BIOS is already at last release, so I needed to change SSD.

Comment: "I know, there are a lot of posts regarding similar problems, but I tried and constantly failed.": please provide some links. Note you are showing your *old* working disk, and not the new one.

Comment: Have you updated UEFI firmware for system and SSD firmware? Even new drive may have an update available. Are you removing old drive before rebooting as you cannot have duplicate UUIDs. Do not run any suggested fixes. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. @oldfred I didnt' understand everything you said: 
1) how can I upgrade an SSD firmware? 
2) I removed the old SSD and put in place the new one before start the system, so only one SSD was in 
3) I put the pastebin link 4) what is ppa? 5) I put the gparted screenshot also for the new SSD, I noticed some differences between the two screenshot but I don't how if they are the problem

Comment: You must have used dd as now backup gpt partition table is not at end of drive. Better to partition in advance & rsync data & then reinstall grub. Or just do new install & rsync from your normal backup. Also confirms backup is good. To move backup to end of drive
 launch gdisk, then type x, then type e, then type w to save your changes http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html http://askubuntu.com/questions/386752/fixing-corrupt-backup-gpt-table/386802#386802 ppa is what you used to download Boot-Repair.

Comment: @oldfred thanks for the advices.
I removed the old SSD, put the new one and start an ubuntu session from live USB. With gdisk I used the command you said x->e->w. Then restart but nothing happened, it stills ask me to insert a disk. Then I put the old SSD, made a backup of the partition table using gdisk using b command. Then I put again the new SSD, and from live ubuntu I tried to load the backup partition table using the commands r->l, but it told me "Warning! Current disk size doesn't match that of the backup!
Adjusting sizes to match, but subsequent problems are possible!".

Comment: You do not want them to be the same size. The backup gpt partition table has to be at the end of the drive. All these types of issues are why I normally suggest a new install & restore from backup. You can install to a SSD in 10 to 15 min, copy data depending on how much, but lot faster than dd, and export list of apps from old install & restore to new install. All that should be your normal backup.

Comment: @oldfred thanks for the suggestions. When you talk about install what you refer about? Install the Os from scratch? Or is something different? I wouldn't install os from scratch because then I have also to reinstall all the apps, and saved passwords and so on...

Comment: If you export list of apps, it is easy to reinstall. All user data should be in /home so restore of /home will include app settings & passwords. Even install to external SSD is less than 10 min. Your should have everything backed up as when (not if) drive fails you have to do new install.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages & http://askubuntu.com/questions/464701/find-out-what-packages-were-installed-after-os-install & http://askubuntu.com/questions/545655/backup-your-home-directory-with-rsync-and-skip-useless-folders

Comment: I have new info on the problem. I installed ubuntu on the new SSD from scratch, but at the boot the system continue to say "insert system disk in drive". Then I removed it and placed in the SSD-USB converter, and then I tried to boot it from USB and it worked... What can it mean?